# How to set Student Post Permissions from Google Classroom API

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-classroom

The Google Classroom API (with the google-php-api-client) allows a web application to create courses, and enroll Students in that course. However, the Google Classroom web site, under the Students tab, has a select with the following options:

From the post and comment list, choose a permission level:

- Students can post and comment
- Students can only comment
- Only teacher can post or comment

How can I set this post permission with the Google Classroom API?

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of option is not executable with the Classroom API itself. As of now, you need to manually set up this in the [Google Classroom website](https://classroom.google.com/h) itself.

If you check the Google Classroom API documentation [reference](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/), there is no method or request that is specific for the students permission or can do these things involving the students.

I found here a related topic that asking about permission setting through API. The only workaround of the user that ask this question is by manually set the permissions with the Google Classroom UI and not through the API.

For more information, check this [Manage Teachers and Students](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users) part of the documentation.